# PHPTAL for ZF2 setup

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phptal

I am trying to implement PHPTal for my ZF2 application.

So far I have only found this github project [HERE](https://github.com/pmattmann/ZF2_PhpTalModule).
But after few hours spent on it I am still unable to use it (there is no doc also linked to it).

Except that I haven't been able to find any piece of information about it!!

Do you guys know any tutorials on how to set PHPTal for ZF2 application ?
Thanks!

PS, so far I am using this [package](https://packagist.org/packages/phptal/phptal)

**EDIT**

I am using composer already to get PHPTal package. My main problem is I don't know what to configure so my view understands tal tags